# It was supposed to be displayed in a table form but it displays in one line in the console after compilation

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, output

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){

    int array1[5][5]={{1,1,1,1,0},{1,1,1,0,2},{1,1,0,2,2},{1,0,2,2,2},{0,2,2,2,2}};

    for ( int row  = 0 ; row < 5 ; row ++){
        for ( int col = 0 ; col < 5 ; col ++)
        {
            cout<< array1[row][col]<< " ";
        }
    }

    cout<<endl;         
}
```

Comment: Just move `cout << endl` after the inner loop (i.e. just before `{`)

Comment: This isn't even c. This is c++.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `cout<<endl;` at the end of the outer loop. It will insert a newline character at the end of the output sequence and flush it:

```
for ( int row  = 0 ; row < 5 ; row ++){
    for ( int col = 0 ; col < 5 ; col ++)
    {
        cout<< array1[row][col]<< " ";
    }
    cout<<endl; // you need to create a new line at the end of each row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to output the new line character after printing each row of the 2D array.

Also you could use the range-based for statement for this purpose.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    int array1[N][N] =
    {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 2 },
        { 1, 1, 0, 2, 2 },
        { 1, 0, 2, 2, 2 },
        { 0, 2, 2, 2, 2 }
    };

    for ( size_t row  = 0 ; row < N ; row++ )
    {
        for ( size_t col = 0 ; col < N ; col++ )
        {
            std::cout << array1[row][col]<< ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;  

    for ( const auto &row : array1 )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 1 1 1 0 
1 1 1 0 2 
1 1 0 2 2 
1 0 2 2 2 
0 2 2 2 2 

1 1 1 1 0 
1 1 1 0 2 
1 1 0 2 2 
1 0 2 2 2 
0 2 2 2 2
```